# Match Function does not work on 2 identical numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-2013

I have 2 identical numbers which get used individually in match functions. However, the latter value returns a #N/A error. I have done all the checks to see if they were truly identical. Checked if both values equaled each other, made sure there were no blanks, used functions (exact, value, istext, isnumber, isnontext), multiplying by 1, etc. Does anyone know what I have missed? Below is a onedrive link to the file which has the exact problem I'm facing.

[file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!As35wKV6v7SHizUNQcAsCyGfREaR)

An interesting observation I made the next day. If I round cell A2 to >3 decimal (even went as far as 10000), the match function works. But I still don't understand what's causing the formulas in cell B2 not to work

Comment: hard to tell With protected sheet

Comment: Also, it would be handy if you can provide a snapshot of the worksheet

Comment: Done a copy and paste and used `=MATCH(A2,$D$1:$D$3)` but it worked as expected... Anything I've missed here?

Comment: @krib - Are you not able to open the link and download the file and that way remove the protected property and see the formulas and value formats

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - If you don't change the values in A1 and A2, and use the formula you suggested, it defaults the lookup to a "TRUE" match_type and hence row#1 is returned and not row#2. I don't want to copy and paste the value in A1 to A2 to fix the issue but understand the underlying problem with cell A2 so I can avoid it in the future

Comment: It worked, firt I checked two values were the same and apply '=match(BI15,$BL$14:$BL$16,0)' as worked as desired

Comment: @Moreno - your formula seems the same as mine, so did you change the value in cell A2

Comment: No i changed no value maybe you are missing the parameter for exact match in the formula

Comment: No I haven't, in fact i have tested it with both a 0 which gives me a N/A error and 1 which gives me a value 1 as expected

Comment: Weird, if you break down the formula with F9 to calculate parts all seems well and the formula actually works! `=MATCH(0.683,{0.682;0.683;0.684},0)` but leaving the formula as is does not. This should not happen, perhaps you've spotted a bug for Microsoft to iron out...

Comment: Literally just entering the formula bar of A2 allows excel to automatically format it how it's happy with but copy and paste values doesn't, mind boggled!!! If you needed to sort out a large data set you'd actually have to build a macro to input the same value again which isn't ideal.

Comment: I have opened a ticket for you on Microsoft website and here is the [link](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/20568346-bug)

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what I have missed?

Globally Replace `.` (by `.`).